# Is there a way to install python 3 and python 2 in the same conda environment?

Tags: python, installation, version, conda

I am trying to create a pipeline but one of the packages I need uses python2 only.  I want everything installed in the same environment so when I send out the pipeline to people I can give them a single `conda create --name pipeline_env blah blah blah`.

Is it possible to do this but have `python3` as the default python version but have `python2` as an executable in `bin`?

Comment: If you use a pipeline tool like [Snakemake](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), you can [define distinct Conda envs for different steps](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html#integrated-package-management) in your pipeline. This is how I deal with this situation in developing bioinformatics pipelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this will not be possible.  In the top level of the conda environment, you will have a python executable:

```
/env_name
  - python (or python.exe on Windows)
```

Asking conda to install python v2 to the environment will **replace** the python 3.x executable with the 2.7.x version of python.

However, you CAN create a new conda environment **inside** an existing environment.  It would be very wierd, but you could do it to maintain encapsulation.

```
conda create -n pipeline_env blah blah blah
conda create -p /path/to/pipeline_env/subenv/pipline_v2
```

Comment: I don't see why this is not inherently impossible. Obviously, the `python` executable has to refer to one version or the other (probably 3) but that doesn't mean you could not also have a python2 executable in the same environment. Python's version-specific directories all have the version number in them, so the only conflict would be that one executable. However, I don't know if there is an easy way to set this up using `conda install`

Comment: Sorry. But I am not likely to try. Python 2 is going away pretty soon and for my use cases there are other ways around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, can the package be migrated to python3? Here is some python documentation that talks about the same
https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Alternately, access the module using rpc / http (overhead - not a bright idea)
 1. Wrap your python2 and execute using rpc
 2. Use a flask or other micro frameworks and call your package